# Use a condition inside a SQL Server 2016 WITH and OPENJSON to change the update value

Tags: sql-server-2016

I currently have in a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure

```
@pmidInfo NVARCHAR(MAX) ='{"pmid":"31390573","journal":"Cell Rep","issn":"","essn":"2211-1247","sortpubdate":"2019/08/06 00:00","pubYear":"2019"}'

SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENJSON (@pmidInfo)  
     WITH (   
              pmid     varchar(15)   '$.pmid',  
              journal  nvarchar(500) '$.journal',  
              issn     varchar(10)   '$.issn',  
              essn     varchar(10)   '$.essn',  
              sortpubdate  varchar(15)  '$.sortpubdate',
              pubYear  varchar(10)   '$.pubYear'  
          )

UPDATE #TempTable
SET issn = REPLACE(essn, '-', '')
WHERE issn = ''
```

Is there a way that I can do the `UPDATE` inside the `OPENJSON` so that it is done more efficiently? I'm new to using `WITH` and `OPENJSON`.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this `SELECT pmid, journal, [insert column names], REPLACE(essn, '-', '') AS essn INTO ... FROM ....`

Comment: Totally understand- THANK YOU I was fixated on the area of code after the WITH and never considered the Select *.  Actually feel like a dumb ass for not seeing that.

Comment: Glad it helped.